# Who is Writing This? Who am I?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, vedanta, advaita, brahma-sutras

When I write this, is it the mind that is making me write this, or the Self? Is the mind always consciously achieved? Is the self never perceived consciously? Was the true Arjun (the Self) listening to Krishna's words or was it the mind that thought it was Arjun? Was Krishna (the Self) talking, or was it the mind that understood it was not the Self?

For any answerer, are you (the Self) answering, or is the mind thinking and answering?

Comment: Self means soul, the one that is making you write this is mind. And not soul

Comment: You are you and the body is the chariot. Buddhi is the charioteer who control the manas or the reins. Your indriyas are the horses. So let’s say when you wrote this, you wrote it but you ordered your buddhi (charioteer) to give effect to writing this question by thinking and taking necessary action, who via the reins (manas) signalled to the horses (karmendriyan) to take the body or in this case your fingers (chariot) a specific direction. So you via the manas controlled the karmendriyan to make the body write this question. Sorry it was little confusing.

Comment: @Archit But, according to the Advaita, isn't you (i.e. the Self) the nirgun, nirakara Bhramah, which both the Gita and the Advaita say is actionless? How can I (the Self) direct the budhee when the Self is actionless?

Comment: @Archit Who is the passenger on the chariot? The Self/Atman/Nirakara Bhramah? Shouldn't I, the Self, be the actionless passenger on the Chariot? Or is the passenger the Jiva-atma?

Comment: The one who asked this question is the drop of infinite immortal Atman, who thinks its a limited bodysuit made of 5 elements under the ego of Maya and given name user758469 or Mr. X in material world by temporary society till body's death or Self-realization.

Comment: @Mr. Sigma: Yes it does. Thanks to everyone too!

Comment: @ManuKumar So to clarify: when the drop of Atman is enclosed in Maya, that drop can forget about its divine origin without the practice of Yoga, as outlined in the Gita. However, when the drop of Atman is outside of the controls of Maya, it understands its divine nature fully forever. Kind of like how Adi Shankaracharya, through mediation and yoga, realized he was none other than the Self/Atman but during his life, since he was surrounded in Maya, there were some times when he got deluded (for instance him meeting the Chandala, Shiva in disguise). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, Atman is same in all, just like water from any water source has same formula H2O, but only clean distilled water is fit for drinking, not ocean or muddy water, similarly only yogis know themselves as Atman, not common others who identify 'I' as material body, while Sadhakas are in the process. Spirit is same in all and its study and realization is Spirituality.